# Does Animal Shapes continually refresh a creature's Hit Points?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, hit-points, polymorph

Looking at the *[Animal Shapes](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Animal%20Shapes)* spell (PHB pg.212) it says:

> On subsequent turns, you can use your action to transform affected creatures into new forms.

Followed by the usual transformation rules:

- They revert to their original form if they drop to 0 HP or die.
- Excess damage is carried over if they revert to their *original* form.
- Their stats are replaced with the stats of the new form, save for Int, Wis, and Char scores.
- They assume the hit points of the new form etc.

Given that it says nothing about damage being carried over from one form to another and "they assume the HP of the new form", it would certainly seem that each time the creature is transformed it is also essentially healed of any damage it may have taken in its previous form.

Is this correct? Does a creature get a new, full pool of HP with each transformation or does the damage it takes in one form carry over to the new one?

Comment: In one game I played recently, an NPC was bleeding out, then *pop!* He turned into  sheep to stop himself from dying.

Answer (score 11):

> On subsequent turns, you can use your action to transform affected creatures into new forms.

And

> The target assumes the hit points of its new form, and when
>   it reverts to its normal form, it returns to the number
>   of hit points it had before it transformed.

"its new form" appears in both places and must have the same meaning so, **yes**, each time it assumes a new form it gets the new hit points.

Doesn't seem particularly OP for an 8th level spell.

Comment: Honestly, it's not so much "OP" as "sole redeeming feature". By the time you can cast this, turning your allies into animals is basically completely worthless.